# ¿Se puede instalar Netbeans y ApacheNetbeans en un mismo PC?

Tags: netbeans

Hace poco me compre un computador nuevo, yo siempre he usado Netbeans pero en este caso me instalé el ApacheNetbeans.

O me sugieren cambiar alguna dirección de instalación o instancia?

Quiero saber si es posible o si genera errores, busqué opiniones de Netbeans y BlueJ y esos si se pueden instalar en un mismo PC.

Comment: Que versiones tienes instaladas? Quieres saber si por ejemplo te dará problemas el hecho de tener Netbeans 8.X y Apache Netbeans 11.X?

Comment: si en este caso netbeans 8.2 y  Apache 11.2

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo tengo así, no deberías de tener ningún problema, instala la versión con los plugins que más te convengan, de todas formas recuerdo que cuando instalé Apache Netbeans 11.2 ya tenía el Netbeans 8.2 y me detectó la configuración e hizo una especie de importación previa, ajustes personales temas y demás (primera vez que abres el 11.2).

Podrías seguir usando la versión 8.2 y la 11.2 a la vez sin problema alguno. Funcionan de forma independiente.